# R: Why does \s{2} return "\"," in regex match? And new line not matching with \\n or \\r and other variations

Tags: r, regex

I'm having trouble with (1) using a dynamic variable in a regex pattern and (2) matching "\" or new line. I'd really appreciate any help!

---

**Example**: Ultimately, however possible, I'd like to match the word `Administrator` in the text file below. The text file's data classification is `character` (it was originally a `list` and was coerced to `character` using `as.character()`. Here's the text snippet:

```
[1] "c(\"Silk Road Forums\", \"\", \"*\", \"Welcome, Guest. Please login or register.\", \"[          ] [          ] [Forever] [Login]\", \"Login with username, password and session length\", \"[                    ]  [Search] \", \"\", \"  â\\200¢ Home\", \"  â\\200¢ Search\", \"  â\\200¢ Login\", \"  â\\200¢ Register\", \"\", \"\", \"  â\\200¢ Silk Road Forums Â»\", \"  â\\200¢ Profile of Dread Pirate Roberts Â»\", \"  â\\200¢ Summary\", \"\", \"  â\\200¢ Profile Info\", \"      â–¡ Summary\", \"      â–¡ Show Stats\", \"      â–¡ Show Posts...\", \"          â\\230† Messages\", \n\"          â\\230† Topics\", \"          â\\230† Attachments\", \"\", \"[profile_sm]Summary\", \"\", \"Dread Pirate Roberts Administrator\", \"\", \"[index]\", \"      â–¡ SMF | SMF Â© 2013, Simple Machines\"\n)"
```

---

**Attempts / Problems**

1. **Tried to Match New Line:** In that messy text (see above), I was able to match `[profile_sm]Summary\`.  I tried to match what comes next in that text by using:

   - `\\n` -- failed
   - `\\n\\r` -- failed
   - `\\n|\\r` -- failed
   - `\\r\\n` -- failed
   - `\\r|\\n` -- failed

   It seems like there's no new line after so I tried to match the literal ""," (inside quotation marks: quotation mark and comma) that comes after characters in that text. So I also tried these two and they both failed: `\\`and `\\"\"`.
2. **Tried to Use Variable:** I tried to use variable `X` that includes `Dread Pirate Roberts` from a previous regex match turned into a vector. I tried to just put `X` into the regex pattern but it obviously didn't work. Is there  away to create a pattern using `X`? For example: Match one of the values found in `x`.

---

I would need to know how to solve both of these problems / methods for other parts of my current project and would really love pointers and guidance. Thank you!

---

**Edit Note**: Saw that folks had trouble understanding this post so I edited to make it more legible. Thanks and shout-out to @Wiktor Stribiżew for reading through the original post despite the difficult wording and providing the answer! :)

Comment: Hi Bob, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm having difficulty understanding what rules you are hoping to apply to arrive at your desired output.

Comment: Hi @IanCampbell, I edited the original post to make it more legible. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text only contains two newlines, you can easily check it using `cat(text)` and there are three lines:

```
c("Silk Road Forums", "", "*", "Welcome, Guest. Please login or register.", "[ ] [ ] [Forever] [Login]", "Login with username, password and session length", "[ ] [Search] ", "", " â�¢ Home", " â�¢ Search", " â�¢ Login", " â�¢ Register", "", "", " â�¢ Silk Road Forums Â»", " â�¢ Profile of Dread Pirate Roberts Â»", " â�¢ Summary", "", " â�¢ Profile Info", " â–¡ Summary", " â–¡ Show Stats", " â–¡ Show Posts...", " â�† Messages", 
" â�† Topics", " â�† Attachments", "", "[profile_sm]Summary", "", "Dread Pirate Roberts Administrator", "", "[index]", " â–¡ SMF | SMF Â© 2013, Simple Machines"
)
```

So, as you see, there is no newline after `[profile_sm]Summary`. Note to match `[` in a regex pattern you need to escape it.. There is a space, `"` and commas You may match these chars using `[,"\s]+` pattern. The `X` variable will hold `Dread Pirate Roberts`, so, to extract `Administrator` you may use

```
\[profile_sm]Summary[",\s]*Dread Pirate Roberts\s+\K[^"]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bwth1Z/1/).

**Details**

- `\[profile_sm]Summary`  - `[profile_sm]Summary` string
- `[",\s]*` - 0+ `"`, `,` or whitespace chars
- `Dread Pirate Roberts`  -  a literal string
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards text matched so far in the match memory buffer
- `[^"]+` - 1+ chars other than `"`. If you need to only match letter, digits or `_` you may use `\w+` instead of this pattern (with `\\` in the string literal).

R demo:

```
text <- "c(\"Silk Road Forums\", \"\", \"*\", \"Welcome, Guest. Please login or register.\", \"[ ] [ ] [Forever] [Login]\", \"Login with username, password and session length\", \"[ ] [Search] \", \"\", \" â\200¢ Home\", \" â\200¢ Search\", \" â\200¢ Login\", \" â\200¢ Register\", \"\", \"\", \" â\200¢ Silk Road Forums Â»\", \" â\200¢ Profile of Dread Pirate Roberts Â»\", \" â\200¢ Summary\", \"\", \" â\200¢ Profile Info\", \" â–¡ Summary\", \" â–¡ Show Stats\", \" â–¡ Show Posts...\", \" â\230† Messages\", \n\" â\230† Topics\", \" â\230† Attachments\", \"\", \"[profile_sm]Summary\", \"\", \"Dread Pirate Roberts Administrator\", \"\", \"[index]\", \" â–¡ SMF | SMF Â© 2013, Simple Machines\"\n)"
X <- "Dread Pirate Roberts"
regex <- paste0('\\[profile_sm]Summary[",\\s]*',X,'\\s+\\K[^"]+')
regmatches(text, regexpr(regex, text, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "Administrator"
```

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribiżew, thank you so much! It looks like based on other comments that my post wasn't clear but you answered my question fully. Really appreciate the help. Accepted the answer +1!

Comment: Would you be able to help with one more thing? When I assign multiple usernames to X (e.g. "DPR", "ABC," "WEF), and use a vector of  multiple text files (same length as X),  I get the following error: `argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: @bob If you have `X <- c("Dread Pirate Roberts","DPR", "ABC", "WEF")`, you need `paste0('\\[profile_sm]Summary[",\\s]*(?:',paste(X, collapse="|"),')\\s+\\K[^"]+')`

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew! Really appreciate it